# How can I select current price of cryptocurrency? Get an coin with ID from API (CoinGecko API)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am not sure how am I able to select current price of coin when I get response like this:
[image]

So in this case I have accesed to a current price of bitcoin like this:

```
getCoin() {
   return this.cryptoAPIService.getCoinById(this.id).subscribe(res => {
     console.log(res);
     this.currentPrice = this.numberWithCommas(res[22].current_price.usd);
 });
```

but when I click on ETHEREUM, response look like this:

[image]

now I get the error because I have to select current price of ethereum like this: `res[23].current_price.usd`. Some of them have current price on index of 24, so I am not sure how am I able to select the current price of all of them with one function, any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

```
getCoinById(id: any) {
    return this.http.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/"+id).
    pipe(
    map(data => Object.keys(data).map(k => data[k]))
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mapping the data to an array, do not do that.

Remove this line:

```js
  map(data => Object.keys(data).map(k => data[k]))
```

Comment: Yeah I don't understand why do I get response like this as an array and not as an object like u can see on images. I  provided u code where I call API, please check it.

Comment: @Kruno I've updated my answer based on your new code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `switch` statement to conditionally handle the different response types.

```js
switch (res[0]) {
  case 'bitcoin':
    // ...
    break;
  case 'ethereum':
    // ...
    break;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I have list of 50 coins which I get from coingecko API.

Comment: If they're all different, you need to handle them individually. If some are the same, use cascading switch cases.